# Security issues surrounding the runtime engine in jbpm 6.1?

Tags: java, security, jbpm

In the JBPM remote API one can get access to a jbpm deployment with code similar to this:

```
RemoteRestRuntimeFactory restSessionFactory 

 = new RemoteRestRuntimeFactory(deploymentId, baseUrl, user, password);


// Create KieSession and TaskService instances and use them

RuntimeEngine engine = restSessionFactory.newRuntimeEngine();

KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();

ProcessInstance processInstance =        ksession.startProcess("com.burns.reactor.maintenance.cycle");

long procId = processInstance.getId();
```

What I wonder is, does the hard-coding of a username and password here cause any security issues? If so, how could one get around them?

EDIT:

More specifically, if the password is hard-coded in clear-text and encoded into the RemoteRestRuntimeFactory object can this cause any issues when sent over a network.

Comment: where is the hard-coding?

Comment: The code I posted is a sample from the website, but in practice the 'user' and 'password' would be hard-coded afaik.

Comment: I suspect that this question can only be answered by someone who is intimately familiar with JBPM, which is what I expect will happen eventually.

Comment: another option would be to put more information into the question about your security concerns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the client code is using HTTP Basic authentication mechanism [[1]](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-remote/kie-remote-common/src/main/java/org/kie/remote/common/rest/KieRemoteHttpRequest.java#L1040).

If your KIE Workbench is not using HTTPS, then I think your password is travelling as plain-text (base64ed though) through the network. It's worth to mention that the client code seems to have support for HTPPS.

Maybe some of the jBPM developers could shed some light here.

Hope it helps,